# $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of functions which are continuous over $[0, 1]$ and continuously differentiable in $(0, 1)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of functions which are continuous over $[0, 1]$ and continuously differentiable in $(0, 1)$. Assume that $|f_n(x)| \leq 1$ and that $|f_n’(x)| \leq 1$ for all $x \in(0, 1)$ and for each positive integer $n$. Pick out the true statements.
(a) $f_n$ is uniformly continuous for each $n$.
(b) $\{f_n\}$ is a convergent sequence in $C[0, 1]$.
(c) $\{f_n\}$ contains a subsequence which converges in $C[0, 1]$.

---

I am totally stuck.  How should I solve this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think the title of the post is entirely too long for being so nondescript, but I could not come up with a better title.

Comment: Do you know any theorems about uniform continuity?  Or about convergent subsequences?  If you know any, you might want to try them and say why they help or don't help.

Comment: $[0,1]$ is compact. You might know a theorem on continuous functions on a compact space? Also, try a simple alternating sequence of constant functions to kill (b), and look up Arzela-Ascoli to see if it applies to c).

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219377/show-that-f-n-is-equicontinuous-given-uniform-convergence/219402#219402).

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**

(a) $[0,1]$ is compact. Probably you know a theorem like this:

> Let $(X,d)$ a compact metric space and $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous. Then...

(b) What about $f_n(x) := (-1)^n$?

(c) Apply Arzelà-Ascoli. (Use $|f_n(x)| \leq 1$, $|f_n'(x)| \leq 1$. Think about mean-value theorem to prove one of the conditions.)

Comment: But I can not understand how to prove that ${f_n}$ is closed?

Comment: @sani What do you mean by closedness of a function?