# Pointwise bounded subsequence convergence

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f_n : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a sequence of differentiable functions that is pointwise bounded. Assume in addition that $|f_n'(x)| \leq 1$ for all $n \geq 1$ and all $x \in [a,b]$. Prove that some subsequence of $(f_n)$ is uniformly convergent.

I'm not really sure where to start

Comment: Do you know the Ascoli-Arzela Teorem?

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219377/show-that-f-n-is-equicontinuous-given-uniform-convergence/219402#219402).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: By mean Value theorem We have $|\frac{f_n(x)-f_n(y)}{x-y}|=|f_n'(c_n)|<1$,try to show by the given data $f_n$s are uniformly bounded equicontinous, Now apply Arzela-Ascolli Theorem.

Comment: What about the condition that $(f_n)$ is uniformly bounded?

Comment: @carl It also follows from the MVT that $|f_n(x)| \le |f_n'(c)||x| + |f_n(0)|$ which combines with the two conditions you are given to yield uniform boundedness.